# Separate Web application using sub domain name in Azure

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, website-hosting

We are developing an online CRM Saas product in .Net Framework. Now we want to provide this service to anyone.

Any user wants to use or try our service they just need to put a few basic details and click on Sign up.

There is one best example of my above statement is confluence, as soon as I sign up with some site name my confluence portal is stared.

https://www.atlassian.com/try/cloud/signup?bundle=confluence

Now how to do the same in Azure, I have only files and folder of my application. How to create separate websites for multiple users with a single domain name. If I programmatically created multiple azure apps using Azure ARM then it becomes very difficult to maintain our product. How to do achieve this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

To host multiple apps under a single domain, if you’re leveraging Azure Web App and deploy your web applications to each virtual directory with the name which could identify your web application.

You could keep your web sites in separate projects and use the ‘virtual directories and applications’ settings in Azure to publish the two different projects under the same site.
Go to WebApp -> Settings -> Application Settings -> Virtual applications and directories.

In Web Apps, each site and its child applications run in the same application pool. If your site has multiple child applications utilizing multiple application pools, consolidate them to a single application pool with common settings or migrate each application to a separate web app.

You may want to check the blog post Deploying multiple virtual directories to a single Azure Website for more details.
Also, you could also use Application Gateway infront of your app since you can do path based routing with app gateway i.e testing.com/one points to one web app and testing.com/another points to the other app. You could start out with the example below the modify the back end to use path-based routing. Kindly refer the links below one that covers the basics of configuring the App Gateway with a WebApp and one discussing path based routing:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/waws/2017/11/21/setting-up-application-gateway-with-an-app-service-that-uses-azure-active-directory-authentication/

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/application-gateway-create-url-route-portal#create-a-path-based-routing-rule